# MYSQL - Highest value on left join before group together

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want my left join to be sorted by ID DESC, but I don't get it to work.

```
SELECT u.ID,
       u.ftyp,
       u.navn,
       u.etternavn,
       u.adresse,
       u.status,
       u.kontaktperson,
       u.email,
       u.telenr
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY ftyp ASC, navn ASC) AS u LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM `timesheet` ORDER BY ID DESC) AS t ON t.userID = u.ID 
GROUP BY t.userID
ORDER BY u.ftyp ASC, t.ID DESC
```

First sort after ftyp, then the highest ID in timesheet before it groups together.

Edit:

If you look at

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXNmB.png)

The result here should be

John, Thea, Erik, Hot

Comment: i think u need to change the order as `ORDER BY t.ID DESC, u.ftyp ASC`

Comment: may I ask why you want a left join sorted?

Comment: Because if a user has put a new post in timesheet I want it to get on top after ftyp(company type)

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the results you want for that data? You are using sorts in the sub queries, and they shouldn't have any effect (they might, but the effects are more by mistake rather than design, and could change at any time)

Comment: This query works under certain sql mode settings only, which are **disabled** by default in the newer mysql versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any sample data it is very difficult to work out what you want.

However you are sorting the data prior to the join and the results of that are not determined. Might be what you want, or might not. But might change with future versions of MySQL or even just swapping the database engine.

The LEFT OUTER JOIN seems irrelevant (unless you want 1 random users details due to the GROUP BY to represent ALL those who have no timesheets).

It would appear best to use a sub query to get the latest timesheet for each user, and then join that to the users and the timesheets. Assuming the timesheet table has a unique id field which is ascending then something like this:-

```
SELECT u.ID,
       u.ftyp,
       u.navn,
       u.etternavn,
       u.adresse,
       u.status,
       u.kontaktperson,
       u.email,
       u.telenr
FROM `user` u 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT userID, MAX(id) AS max_id FROM `timesheet` GROUP BY userID
) t_sub 
ON t_sub.userID = u.ID 
INNER JOIN `timesheet` t
ON t_sub.userID = t.userID
AND t_sub.max_id = t.id
ORDER BY u.ftyp ASC, t.ID DESC
```

Comment: @AndersNilsson - Try it now